# Trycatching invoking of the UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, thread-safety, backgroundworker

I've made an app that runs around the clock with three `Backgroundworkers` running in different intervals.

In their `DoWork` i do some `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` so it updateds some charts. The problem is that its crashing during the night and I'm unsure why. I've wrapped the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` in try/catch, but since I'm invoking the UI thread, I'm thinking I maybe do the try catch *INSIDE* the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` instead.

Does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

test if the EventArgs Error property is not null in the RunWorkerCompleted method

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

The `try/catch` will only work with the stuff that's happening in its current thread. If an error happened in another thread, the worker will finish but you don't know why unless you inspect the `Error` property.

Comment: *If an error happened in another thread, the worker will finish but you don't know why unless you inspect the Error property.* **This statement is incorrect.** `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error` is only for errors thrown on the worker thread, not any other thread. [More details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21301435/1768303). Many people up-voted this, **am I missing something?**

Answer (score 1):

A callback queued with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` is asynchronous. You should observe **all exceptions inside the delegate you pass into `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`**, because they are not getting propagated anywhere outside it (except as `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException`, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` events and as `DispatcherOperation.Task.Exception` property, see below). If they go unhanded, they will crash the app inside the core `Dispatcher` event loop on the UI thread.

This includes `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error` too. An exception thrown inside `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` delegate **will not be available there** as `Error`, upon `RunWorkerCompletedEvent` event.

Here is a **simple example illustrating** the problem. Note how `e.Error` is `null` inside `RunWorkerCompleted`:

```
// UI Thread

// prepare the message window
var window = new Window 
{ 
    Content = new TextBlock { Text = "Wait while I'm doing the work..." },
    Width = 200,
    Height = 100
};

// run the worker
var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
    // do the work 
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // update the UI
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Catch me if you can!");
    }));

    // do more work
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
};

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    // e.Error will be null
    if (e.Error != null)
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
    // close the message window
    window.Close();
};

// start the worker
worker.RunWorkerAsync();

// show the modal message window 
// while the worker is working
window.ShowDialog();
```

**To solve the problem**, observe the exceptions with something like this:

```
var step = 0; // progress

// do the work on a background thread
// ..

var lastStep = step++;
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
{
    try 
    {
        // do the UI update
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // log or report the error here
        MessageBox.Show("Error during step #" + 
            lastStep + ": " + ex.ToString());
    }
}));
```

**Alternatively**, you can keep track of all `DispatcherOperation` returned by `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`:

```
var invokes = new List<DispatcherOperation>();

// do the work on a background thread
// ..

invokes.Add(Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    { /* update the UI */ }))));
```

Then you can examine `DispatcherOperation.Task.Exception` of each invocation you've queued with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. I don't think this is feasible though, unless you can prevent the `invokes` list from growing endlessly.